# The form just don't submit even if after all field is filled and checked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am a beginner student in web design and this is a project I was given but no matter what I do the form just won't submit. even if all the input is correct it still doesn't do anything after I click submit. Any help is appreciated. I have googled for an hour but nothing I do works.

This is just a simple structure of a form. My main goal is to validate the code and sent to a PHP script.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <style>
            h1,h2 {
                color:red;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #form {
                padding-left: 80px;
            }
            .fullname{  
                //border:1px solid;
                padding:0 0 0 80px;
                margin:0;
                color:red;
                font-style:italic;
                font-size:13px;
                white-space:nowrap;
                //float:left;
                //visibility:hidden; 
            }
            .N {
                //border-color:red;
                border-radius:5px;
                //text-shadow:0 0 2px #ddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <!--onSubmit="return !!(validateFName() & validateLName() & validateGender() & validateMonth() & validateDay() & validateYear());" -->
        <form id="form" name="myForm" action="new1.php" onSubmit="return validateName()" >
            First Name:<input class="N" type="text" name="fname"  value="enter name 
                here" /><br>
            <div id="errorFName" class="fullname"></div>
            Last Name:<input class="N" type="text" name="lname" value="enter name here"/><br>
            <div id="errorLName" class="fullname"></div>
            Gender:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female<br>
            <div id="gender" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 15px;"></div>
            Date Of Birth:<br>
            Month:
            <select name="month">
                <option value="0">--Select Month--</option>
                <option value="1">Janaury</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            &emsp;
            Day:
            <select name="day">
                <option value='No'>--Select Day--</option>
                <option value='Mo'>Monday</option>
                <option value='tu'>Tuesday</option>
                <option value='we'>Wednesday</option>
                <option value='th'>Thursday</option>
                <option value='fr'>Friday</option>
                <option value='sa'>Saturday</option>
                <option value='su'>Sunday</option>
            </select>
            &emsp;
            Year:
            <select name="year">
                <script>
                    for(var i = 2017; i >= 1900; i--){
                    document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
                    }
                </script>
            </select>
            <br>
            <span id="month_div" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 60px;"></span>
            <span id="day_div" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 80px;"></span>
            <span id="year_div" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 65px;"></span><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
        <script>
            var firstName = document.forms.myForm.fname;
            var lastName = document.forms.myForm.lname;
            var gender = document.forms.myForm.sex;
            var months = document.forms.myForm.month;
            var days = document.forms.myForm.day;
            var years = document.forms.myForm.year;

            var fname_error = document.getElementById("errorFName");
            var lname_error = document.getElementById("errorLName");
            var gender_error = document.getElementById("gender");
            var month_error = document.getElementById("month_div");
            var day_error = document.getElementById("day_div");
            var year_error = document.getElementById("year_div");


            function validateName() {
                var validity = true;
                validity &= validateFName();
                validity &= validateLName();
                validity &= validateGender();
                validity &= validateMonth();
                validity &= validateDay();
                validity &= validateYear();
                return validity;
            }

            function validateFName() {
                if (firstName.value === "enter name here") {
                    firstName.value = "";
                    firstName.style.border = "1px solid red";
                    fname_error.textContent = "Fill User Name";
                    return false;
                }
                if (firstName.value !== "enter name here") {
                    // fname_error.innerHTML = "";   
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function validateLName() {
                if (lastName.value === "enter name here") {
                    lastName.value = "";
                    lastName.style.border = "1px solid red";
                    lname_error.textContent = "Fill User Name";
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function validateGender() {
                if (gender[0].checked || gender[1].checked) {
                    gender_error.innerHTML = "";
                    return true;
                } else {
                    gender_error.textContent = "select your sex";
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function validateMonth() {
                if (months.value !== "0") {
                    month_error.innerHTML = "";
                    day_error.style.padding = "0 0 0 175px";
                    return true;
                } else {
                    month_error.textContent = "select the month";
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function validateDay() {
                if (days.value !== "No") {
                    day_error.innerHTML = "";
                    year_error.style.padding = "0 0 0 150px";
                    return true;
                } else {
                    day_error.textContent = "select the day";
                    //day_error.style.padding = "0 0 0 80px";
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function validateYear() {
                if (years.value !== "2017") {
                    year_error.innerHTML = "";
                    return true;
                } else {
                    year_error.textContent = "select the year";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: just tried to debug it this way and it seems that the code just passed through even if the return value is true.

## the out put is always "it doesnt work"

```
function validateName() {
    var validity = true;
    validity &= validateFName();
    if (validity === true)
        alert("it works FName");
    validity &= validateLName();
    if (validity === true)
        alert("it works LName");
    validity &= validateGender();
    if (validity === true)
        alert("it works Gender");
    validity &= validateMonth();
    if (validity === true)
        alert("it works Month");
    validity &= validateDay();
    if (validity === true)
        alert("it works Day");
    validity &= validateYear();
    alert("it works Year");
    if (validity === true)
        return validity;
    else
        alert("it dosnt works");
}
```

edit 2. now my problem is with submit. it submits the form without validating any input. it should say "please fill the fields" but it just goes to the php file.

Comment: does your console give you any errors?

Comment: Set a break point in the validateName function using Chrome or FireFox and verify that function returns as expected.  You may just want to add a simple alert or console message to verify the function is being called.

Comment: No, none @LucaKiebel

Comment: i edited the post. @MisterPositive

Comment: I suggest you create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. 
It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**.
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. 
You may be asked to amend this code in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code , hope it will work, i update your some code and use placeholder so no need to use check using text and update &= to = and related some code , hope it will work now

```
<html>
<head><title>Form</title>
    <style>
        h1, h2 {
            color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #form {
            padding-left: 80px;
        }

        .fullname {
        / / border: 1 px solid;
            padding: 0 0 0 80px;
            margin: 0;
            color: red;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: 13px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        / / float: left;
        / / visibility: hidden;
        }

        .N {
        / / border-color: red;
            border-radius: 5px;
        / / text-shadow: 0 0 2 px #ddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<!--onSubmit="return !!(validateFName() & validateLName() & validateGender() & validateMonth() & validateDay() & validateYear());" -->
<form id="form" name="myForm" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validateName()">
    First Name:<input class="N" type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="enter namehere"/><br>

    <div id="errorFName" class="fullname"></div>
    Last Name:<input class="N" type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="enter name here"/><br>

    <div id="errorLName" class="fullname"></div>
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female<br>

    <div id="gender" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 15px;"></div>
    Date Of Birth:<br>
    Month:
    <select name="month">
        <option value="0">--Select Month--</option>
        <option value="1">Janaury</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>&emsp;
    Day:
    <select name="day">
        <option value='No'>--Select Day--</option>
        <option value='Mo'>Monday</option>
        <option value='tu'>Tuesday</option>
        <option value='we'>Wednesday</option>
        <option value='th'>Thursday</option>
        <option value='fr'>Friday</option>
        <option value='sa'>Saturday</option>
        <option value='su'>Sunday</option>
    </select>&emsp;
    Year:
    <select name="year">
        <script>
            for (var i = 2017; i >= 1900; i--) {
                document.write('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
            }
        </script>
    </select><br>
    <span id="month_div" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 60px;"></span>
    <span id="day_div" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 80px;"></span>
    <span id="year_div" class="fullname" style="padding:0 0 0 65px;"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
     var firstName = document.forms.myForm.fname;
var lastName = document.forms.myForm.lname;
var gender = document.forms.myForm.sex;
var months = document.forms.myForm.month;
var days = document.forms.myForm.day;
var years = document.forms.myForm.year;

var fname_error = document.getElementById("errorFName");
var lname_error = document.getElementById("errorLName");
var gender_error = document.getElementById("gender");
var month_error = document.getElementById("month_div");
var day_error = document.getElementById("day_div");
var year_error = document.getElementById("year_div");


function validateName() {
    validity = true;
    validity = validateFName();
    validity = validateLName();
    validity = validateGender();
    validity = validateMonth();
    validity = validateDay();
    validity = validateYear();
  //  return validity;
    if(validateFName() && validateLName() && validateGender() && validateMonth() && validateYear()){
        document.getElementById("form").action = "http://localhost/new1.php";
    // change this url which your action
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
function validateFName() {
    if (firstName.value == "") {
        firstName.value = "";
        firstName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        fname_error.textContent = "Fill User Name";
        return false;
    } else {
        fname_error.textContent = "";
        firstName.style.border = "1px solid #fff";
        return true;
    }

}
function validateLName() {
    if (lastName.value == "") {
        lastName.value = "";
        lastName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        lname_error.textContent = "Fill User Name";
        return false;
    } else {
        lname_error.textContent = "";
        lastName.style.border = "1px solid #fff";
        return true;
    }
}
function validateGender() {
    if (gender[0].checked || gender[1].checked) {
        gender_error.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        gender_error.textContent = "select your sex";
        return false;
    }
}
function validateMonth() {
    if (months.value !== "0") {
        month_error.innerHTML = "";
        day_error.style.padding = "0 0 0 175px";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        month_error.textContent = "select the month";
        return false;
    }
}
function validateDay() {
    if (days.value !== "No") {
        day_error.innerHTML = "";
        year_error.style.padding = "0 0 0 150px";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        day_error.textContent = "select the day";
        //day_error.style.padding = "0 0 0 80px";
        return false;
    }
}
function validateYear() {
    if (years.value !== "2017") {
        year_error.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        year_error.textContent = "select the year";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var firstName = document.forms.myForm.fname.value;
```

You have forgot to add value after field name.

Comment: it won't make a difference cause i was using it like   "firstName.value " for the rest of the code

Comment: replace from '&='  to  '=' (Remove &)

It is converting false to 0.

Comment: Thank You very much it solved the checking issue but still, the form doesn't submit after every thing is true. @Cppi Khatri

Comment: Remove var from this line

var validity = true;

change it to 

validity = true;

Comment: now the form just submits without validating any input tags. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use old code.. which you posted here and can change as i mentioned here.
In your old code Just remove '&' and 'var'. This will work as working at my end.

Comment: God Bless You. It Worked. Thank You So Much @Cppi Khatri